# Putting multiple points in a list? - Creating a polygon

Tags: haskell

So, I'm seeking some help with how I would go about this. This is the function.

```
getPolygonGraphic :: [Point] -> ColourName -> Graphic
getPolygonGraphic = ??
```

Polygon is defined by:

```
data Shape = Rectangle Side Side
       | Ellipse   Side Side
       | Polygon   [Point]
       | Line      Point Point
deriving (Show)
```

Also, 'Side' = Double

ColourName is defined by:

```
data ColourName
= Magenta
| Black
| Green
| Yellow
| Orange
| Cyan
deriving (Show)
```

Graphic is:

```
data Graphic =
Graphic Shape
        ColourName
        Point
deriving (Show)
```

My attempt for the right side of the '=' was to have:

```
getPolygonGraphic :: [Point] -> ColourName -> Graphic
getPolygonGraphic = Graphic(Polygon) colourType ()
```

However, I havent added any points as im not sure how to do so with lists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's `Graphic`?

Comment: Sorry pasting error, thought it was in there. Just edited it.

Comment: What happens when you try your attempt?

Comment: Well, My attempt doesnt have variables on the left hand side of the '=' so it wouldnt work. In the (Polygon) part, I think there should be some points, but the points need to be in a list, and im not to sure how I would go about doing that. I need to define the list first on the left hand side i think.

Comment: From the data constructor of `Graphic`, it looks like you have to supply exactly one `Point`. How do you plan to reduce a list of `Point` values to a single `Point`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main doubt here is which point should be the one that is used for the `Graphic` and also how `Point` is defined. By looking at some other questions I'm going to guess that `Point` is `(Int, Int)`.

In this solution I'm using `(0, 0)` as the third value that is received by the `Graphic` constructor:

```
getPolygonGraphic :: [Point] -> ColourName -> Graphic
getPolygonGraphic ps c = Graphic (Polygon ps) c (0, 0)
```

And here I'm using the first `Point` on the array:

```
getPolygonGraphic :: [Point] -> ColourName -> Graphic
getPolygonGraphic (p:ps) c = Graphic (Polygon (p:ps)) c p
```

Just change that value to whichever the coursework said you should use.